# Keeping observations when certain requirements filled

Tags: sas

I'm trying to clean my data of certain observations. I only want to keep the rows in which one of my 10 variables in atleast one place contain a certain value (code). The dataset is very big and can contain a huge number of values for the variables. I might only want to keep the rows where there are observations starting with 'C'. Those can be coded as anything between C000 to CA798 and so on. I also want to keep the row if it somewhere has another observation, but this time it might be UG63000 to UG68999 and UG74. One of the wanted codes only has to come up once per row, but if several of the wanted codes exist somewhere in the row it is not a problem. Later on i want to code these so where ever one of the values of interest exists i get a 1.

The problem therefore is generalizing a drop/keep condition for codes with certain values without having to hard code every single one of the possible values like:
keep if variable1=C000 or if variable1=C0001 or if variable2=C000 or if variable2=UG63 
and so on.

A row might look as such:

ID        Var1          Var2     ...     Var10

Xyz       C700          TI0213   ...     Z892DA

Comment: Please post sample data in `datalines` format and code with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Please provide some sample data so we can test for your situation.)

The question is a bit unclear so I'll provide several possibilities.

> variable1=C000 or if variable1=C0001 or if variable2=C000

if you just want to check if variable1 starts with 'C' then you can already simplify these 3 conditions with 1:

```
variable1 =: 'C'
```

> UG63000 to UG68999 and UG74

what is the rule here?
If the rule is "starting with 'UG'" then

```
variable2 =: 'UG'
```

If the rule is in a predefined list then you could use someting like this:

```
variable2 in ('UG63000','UG68999','UG74')
```

Or you could generalize more with macros.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly written post. I've had problems with adding a decent looking data line as sample due to me being fairly new to the site and not being able to just post a copied dataline since it is sensitive data. However this helped me a great deal. I've been trying to fix it by writing
variable1='C:' (having the colon in the wrong place).
Moving the colon seems to have solved most of my problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into getting your data into a more normalized format so that you have just one variable with the code. Then you could merge to a lookup table to classify the codes.

To make your coding generation easier you could create a macro. Something like:

```
%macro condition(varlist,valuelist);
%local i j sep;
(
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist));
%do j=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&valuelist));
 &sep %scan(&varlist,&i) = %upcase("%scan(&valuelist,&j)")
%let sep=or;
%end;
%end;
)
%mend condition;
```

You could then use it in a WHERE statement. Or to create a new 0/1 variable.

```
%let varlist=var1 var2 var3 ;
data want;
  set have;
  where %condition(&varlist,C0001 C0002);
  diseaseA = %condition(&varlist,D0001 D0002);
end;
```